# Pull to Refresh with Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to implement the Pull to refresh feature on the Angular app. I have tried this. But I cannot do the workflow they have mentioned. Can you tell me how to use this library?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-pull-to-refresh

I don't know how this works?

> Run ng generate component component-name --project ngx-pull-to-refresh to generate a new component

Should I create a new Angular project and try that or within my project can I do that (I tried but errors)? It seems I need to do that on the same project. But no luck yet.

> Note: Don't forget to add --project ngx-pull-to-refresh or else it will be added to the default project in your angular.json file.

They have this too `npm i ngx-pull-to-refresh`. But it doesn't have `</ngx-pull-to-refresh>` component.

When I use their npm and use the component then this?

```
'ngx-pull-to-refresh' is not a known element:
1. If 'ngx-pull-to-refresh' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngx-pull-to-refresh' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

I have registered it correctly on `app.module.ts` and used on the `app.component.html`

Comment: The commands in the readme assume that you have cloned their GitHub repository and run the commands there. You should adapt them based on your needs if you start from a brand new or another Angular project.

Comment: Given your rep, you should know that "I tried but errors" is not useful at all. What *exactly* did you try? What *exactly* happened? Are you using the Angular CLI on your current project?

Comment: @Dzhuneyt It seems your right. Can you construct an answer with more details? Why they have mentioned using `npm publish`?

Comment: Which Angular Version are you using

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm `"@angular/core": "^10.1.5",`

Comment: My last needle, The author of the lib is asian. Could it be, that a character is not the same? Maybe a dash not being the same dash in char code or something like that?

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm No. He is telling something here under the `Code scaffolding` section. But I cannot understand what to do with the existing project https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-pull-to-refresh#code-scaffolding

Comment: I don't think you should pay much attention to that. I just included it into this stackblitz and no error https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mk4zze?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**OP's Feedback**

My issue here was VS code added the wrong `import`. It shows this `import { NgxPullToRefreshModule } from 'ngx-pull-to-refresh/lib/ngx-pull-to-refresh.module';`. No compilation issues on the `ts` file. But it is not working. This module's Readme is super confusing.

But your stackblitz shows the correct one. This `import { NgxPullToRefreshModule } from 'ngx-pull-to-refresh';`

Now it is working.

**Original**

Install the dependency with `npm i ngx-pull-to-refresh` and add the `NgxPullToRefreshModule` to your `app.module`. Then use the element `ngx-pull-to-refresh`as described at github `https://github.com/YeongCheon/ngx-pull-to-refresh#readme.

```
<ngx-pull-to-refresh spinnerColor="#ff0000" spinnerSize="100px" (refresh)="myRefreshEvent($event, 'refresh');" (loadMore)="alert('loadmore');">
  <div style="height: 3000px">long content</div>
</ngx-pull-to-refresh>
```

Comment: Yes, I did that. But `'ngx-pull-to-refresh' is not a known element:
1. If 'ngx-pull-to-refresh' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngx-pull-to-refresh' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.`

Comment: This message declares that you have not import your module in your project correctly.
You should import it into your `AppModule`, or any other module that is created before you use your component.

Comment: @StPaulis This is not my first Angular project. I did all the things. You also can try that if you want.

Comment: Did you restart your `ng serve`? The `ng serve` sometimes doesn't account module changes correctly.

Comment: I did everything. Not only serve but also restart the VS code too.